# How to convert Gregorian dates to Chinese (not Sexagenary Cycle) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nscalendar

I am trying to convert Chinese New Years to the Gregorian calendar.  But I am running into trouble with iOS because the SDK is returning the year between 1 and 60 (the Sexagenary Cycle) not on an absolute scale.  Here is the code from an Xcode playground...

```
let inputGregorianYear = 2020

let chineseCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .chinese)
let gregorianCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

var formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

var gregorianComponents = DateComponents()

gregorianComponents.month = 1
gregorianComponents.day = 25
gregorianComponents.year = inputGregorianYear

let chineseNewYear = gregorianCalendar.date(from: gregorianComponents)

formatter.calendar = chineseCalendar
let chineseDateStr = formatter.string(from: chineseNewYear!)
print("Chinese date: \(chineseDateStr)")     //  Chinese date: 01/01/0037 Should be 01/01/4718?

formatter.calendar = gregorianCalendar
let gregorianDateStr = formatter.string(from: chineseNewYear!)
print("Gregorian date: \(gregorianDateStr)") // Gregorian date: 01/25/2020
```

Seems like I am missing some setting to switch from Sexagenary to normal years but I can't find it anywhere.

More detail... this is the crux of my problem...

```
//  Here is the problem...
let chineseCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .chinese)
let gregorianCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

var components = DateComponents()
components.day = 1
components.month = 1
components.year = 4658

let chineseNewYear = chineseCalendar.date(from: components)

var formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/YYYY"

formatter.calendar = chineseCalendar
let chineseDateStr = formatter.string(from: chineseNewYear!)
print("Chinese date: \(chineseDateStr)")     //  "Chinese date:  01/01/9278" Should be 1/1/4658?

formatter.calendar = gregorianCalendar
let gregorianDateStr = formatter.string(from: chineseNewYear!)
print("Gregorian date: \(gregorianDateStr)") // "Gregorian date: 01/30/6641" Should be 02/12/2021
```

Why doesn't this work?  The formatter fix does not address the components.year.  The only thing that works is components.year in the range of 1..60 for the sexagenary cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is also fine. Just change format to this:

```
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/YYYY"
```

This is how I convert dates.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let date = Date()
let dateInGregorian = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

print(dateInGregorian)

dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .chinese)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
print("Converted date to Chinese = \(dateFormatter.string(from: date))")
```

To convert to Gregorian:

```
dateFormatter.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
print("Converted date to Gregorian = \(dateFormatter.string(from: date))")
```

We have different format when working with chinese date, use **"dd MMM YYYY"**. To convert Chinese to Gregorian

```
func convertDateFrom(dateString: String, dateFormat: String) -> Date? {
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_us")
guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) else {return nil}
return date
}

let dateGregorian = convertDateFrom(dateString: "09/03/4657", dateFormat: "dd MMM YYYY") ?? Date()

print("Converted date to Gregorian = \(dateGregorian)")
```

Comment: Answers are more helpful (to the author of the question and to future readers of this thread) if they *explain* the problem and the solution, instead of posting code only.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for highlighting!

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful!  Follow-up question... how can I convert 1/1/4652 (Chinese Calendar) to Gregorian?  DataComponents(.year) doesn't seem to accept 4652 as a valid input.

Comment: @ScottSarnikowski I have edited answer as per your follow-up question. And it works fine.

Comment: I accepted your answer but your second response doesn't answer my second question.  I have add more detail below...

Comment: @ScottSarnikowski Thanks! You can convert back to Gregorian like i did above.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something...  In my second example, I use DateComponents to enter 1/1/4658, which is a valid date on the Chinese calendar.  I immediately print out the Date using "MM/dd/YYYY" as you suggested and I get "01/01/9278"... not even close.  This is the problem that I am trying to understand...

Comment: @ScottSarnikowski Here you go. To convert back to Gregorian.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got to the bottom of the issue.  My original question could have been more elegantly stated as... "What is the Month and Day of Chinese New Year for a Gregorian year?".  In my journey I learned that the Chinese calendar follows the sexagenary cycle of 60year eras.  Era is an important concept because you need to use it to get to the right Gregorian year.  Not specifying the an Era on the Chinese calendar will return a Month and Day in the current Era which began in 1984.

Here is how I solved the problem of getting the Month and Day of Chinese New Year for any Gregorian year:

```
enter var chineseCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .chinese)

let g_year = 2020
let g_adj_year = g_year + 2697

let c_era = Int(g_adj_year/60)
let c_year = g_adj_year - c_era * 60

var components = DateComponents()
components.era = c_era
components.year = c_year
components.month = 1
components.day = 1

let c_ny = chineseCalendar.date(from: components)!

var gregorianCalendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
gregorianCalendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
formatter.calendar = gregorianCalendar

print("\(formatter.string(from: c_ny))")  // 01/25/2020
```

The 2697 offset to the Gregorian year is critical to get the correct Chinese Era.

Comment: I answered your first question, then you edited your question and now you are answering yourself?

Comment: Got complicated.  To your point, I marked your answer as the answer.  Mine is actually what I was looking for but didn't know how to ask when I asked it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You may face problems in Chinese and Japanese for missing the word "日"
so the solution that solved this for me was using date formatter templates as below:

```
private enum DateFormatters {

        private static func dateFormat(from template: String, locale: Locale) -> String {
            guard let formatterString = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: template, options: 0, locale: locale)
            else {
                assertionFailureOrLog("Invalid Date Format")
                return ""
            }
            return formatterString
        }

        private static func dateFormater(from template: String) -> DateFormatter {
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = dateFormat(from: template, locale: formatter.locale)

            return formatter
        }

        static let dayAndMonthFormatter = dateFormater(from: "Mdyyyy")
    }
```

you can use it like this:

```
let arrivalDate = DateFormatters.dayAndMonthFormatter.string(from: arrivalTime)
```

and below are variant formats that can be used

```
formatdate("Mdyyyy") // "1/2/1984"
formatdate("yyyyMMdd") // "01/02/1984"
formatdate("yyyyMMMdd") // "Jan 02, 1984"
formatdate("yyyyMMMMdd") // "January 02, 1984"
formatdate("yyyyMMMMMdd") // "J 02, 1984"
formatdate("yyyyG") // "1984 AD"
formatdate("yyyyGGGG") // "1984 Anno Domini"
formatdate("yyyyMMMddE") // "Mon, Jan 02, 1984"
formatdate("yyyyMMMddEEEE") // "Monday, Jan 02, 1984"
formatdate("yyyyMMMddEEEEE") // "M, Jan 02, 1984"

formatdate("MdYYYY") // "1/2/1984"
formatdate("YYYYMMdd") // "01/02/1984"
formatdate("YYYYMMMdd") // "Jan 02, 1984"
formatdate("YYYYMMMMdd") // "January 02, 1984"
formatdate("YYYYMMMMMdd") // "J 02, 1984"
formatdate("YYYYG") // "1984 AD"
formatdate("YYYYGGGG") // "1984 Anno Domini"
formatdate("YYYYMMMddE") // "Mon, Jan 02, 1984"
formatdate("YYYYMMMddEEEE") // "Monday, Jan 02, 1984"
formatdate("YYYYMMMddEEEEE") // "M, Jan 02, 1984"
```